# .NET TcpClient disconnects while Python stays connected

Tags: python, vb.net, tcpclient

I have .NET client/server applications that communicate with a line protocol using `TcpClient` and an `SSLStream`. Basically they exchange some information and then enter a heartbeat loop where the client periodically sends a message to the server and receives an answer.
This works well and can do so for days, but sometimes the connection breaks with a Socket error code of either 10054 or 10060, saying the host is unresponsive.
For testing I got rid of most code and tried it with the very minimal components.

On the server I use a `TcpListener` and run this code for new clients in a new task **(please note that I have stripped logging code from the example)**:

```vb
Private Sub HandleClient(c As TcpClient)
    c.NoDelay = True 'I tried with and without this algorithm
    Dim stream = c.GetStream
    Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
    c.ReceiveTimeout = 60000
    Do
        Dim value As Integer = 0
        Try
            value = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        For i = 0 To value - 1
            buffer(i) = 0 'Just to get rid of residuals for error checking
        Next
        stream.Write({1, 45, 26}, 0, 3)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Most is just logging, the values I send are just some random numbers. So here I read the values from a `NetworkStream` and write some numbers back. Note: In the real application I use `WriteLine` and `ReadLine`.

The client code is equally short, it is also started in a new task:

```vb
Private Sub Connect()
    'Get the ip to connect to from the command line, or use localhost
    Dim ip = If(My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0, My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0), "127.0.0.1")
    log("Trying to parse " & ip)
    Dim parsed As IPAddress = Nothing
    If IPAddress.TryParse(ip, parsed) = False Then parsed = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")

    Dim c As New TcpClient()
    c.NoDelay = True
    c.Connect(parsed, 16543)
    Dim stream = c.GetStream
    Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
    Do
        stream.Write({33, 75, 123, 3}, 0, 4)
        Dim value As Integer
        Try
            value = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        For i = 0 To value - 1
            buffer(i) = 0 'Just to get rid of residuals for error checking
        Next
        'Write a message every 5 seconds
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I run this alongside my normal client and server applications and it works flawlessly but disconnects at the exact same time as my normal client/server connection. The quick conclusion is that there is a problem with the internet connection on this device.

However, I also adapted a small python script to do basically the some thing, it connects and exchanges Hello World strings:

Server:

```py
import socket
import time
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

TCP_IP = 'this server'
TCP_PORT = 7777
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        conn.send("World!")
conn.close()
```

Client:

```py
import socket
import time
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

TCP_IP = 'my server'
TCP_PORT = 7777
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
while 1:
    s.send(MESSAGE)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    time.sleep(5)
s.close()
```

I run this as well on the same machines and it has no problem whatsoever. It just keeps on sending, so I guess the internet connection is ok.

The client is behind a NAT router while the server is running on a vServer off-site.

So, to summarize:

1. Two .NET client/server applications experience disconnects at the same time, at random intervals (the can run for hours before a disconnect happens).
2. A python client/server application that seems to do the same task does not experience disconnects.

I am truly out of ideas what the cause of this problem may be.

Things I have tried are:

Using Async read/write operations instead of synchronous, enabling/disabling Nagle's algorithm (`NoDelay`), sending raw bytes instead of using `WriteLine`/`ReadLine`.
It may be machine or connection dependent, as two other test clients on other connections seem to be running stable for the last few days. But it also seems implementation dependent, because the Python script works forever.

Sorry for the wall of text/code, I'm grateful for any idea about where I went wrong.

Comment: You are saying the code works fine for some days and then it just stops working? This looks like the server is not listening on the port anymore. Make sure the server is always listening. If you are using AcceptClient Change this to AcceptSocket. You might also have a case like this one. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981344/an-application-may-receive-the-10054-error-when-the-application-receiv

Comment: @Chillzy I am currently experimenting with stripping out the TcpClient and NetworkStream stuff and reducing it to raw Socket use. But the link you sent is very interesting as well, since it is the case that my two working test clients use Win10 while the non-working one uses Win7. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same happens when I write the server/client with `Socket`s only, and the Hotfix doesn't seem to apply to my version of Win7.